# Direct3D11 - Access violation executing location xxx on CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow

Tags: c++, uwp, direct2d, direct3d11

I am learning C++ and Direct3D11/Direct2D (on top of UWP) for fun, but am struggling getting my little test program to run. It throws an access violation (see below for exact exception) when I call CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow.

I used the D3D Device for other calls and they worked so I don't think that is the issue. The swap chain description is relatively straight-forward and the swap chain itself will be set in the call. So, I assume that the exception is because I am passing an incorrect pointer to the window but I can't solve it.

Exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8FE44F4E0 (Windows.UI.dll) in UWP D2D example v3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00007FF8FE44F4E0.

Code snippet (https://github.com/cwebb95/Direct2D_cppwinrt):

```
        ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain = nullptr;
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(m_d3dDevice.Get(),
                                        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(&CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()),
                                        &swapChainDescription,
                                        NULL,    
                                        &swapChain));
```

Comment: Could you tell me the kind of the project you are using? Could you please provide us with  a sample code by using Onedrive or GitHub?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added a GitHub repository of the code. Also, it is a C++ winrt project.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem by changing the second parameter to:

```
static_cast<::IUnknown*>(winrt::get_abi(CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()))
```

from:

```
reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(&CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread())
```

I am not knowledge enough yet to know why that fixed the problem, but I will research and hopefully figure it out (any leads on that question would be much appreciated).

Comment: DXGI needs the ``IUnknown*`` interface to your core window object, not the C++/WinRT projection objection or a C++/CX pointer. That's why you have to explicitly convert it to to the "ABI" which is a COM pointer you can convert to ``IUnknown*``. See [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for a bunch of examples of different device & swapchain set ups for Win32 and UWP.

Comment: I had just debugged enough to figure out it was the conversion to ABI rather than the reinterpret_cast that was causing the issue. Thank you for the explanation of why that is the case. Very helpful!

Comment: It can also be a little confusing because C++/CX (``/ZW``) does the 'ABI conversion' trick automatically if you use ``reinterpret_cast`` from a WinRT^ to a IUnknown*. For C++/WinRT, you have to be explicit with ``get_abi``.